# C# SQLiteを操作するクラスをクラスライブラリ化したときにInterop.dllを要求される点について

Tags: c#, sqlite, dll, nuget

お世話になります。

つい以前、SQliteの接続について質問し、一度解決したと思ったのですが、望む通りの結果に至らなかったため、再度別の内容で質問させていただきます。前回回答していただいた方々には本当に申し訳のないことをしてしまいました。

SQLiteを簡単に操作できるクラスライブラリを作ろうと、『SQLitePackage』という名で新規に
『Windowsフォームアプリケーション』としてプロジェクトを作り、NuGetでSystem.Data.SQLite.Coreをインストールし、SQLiteのファイルのデータベースアクセスするコード(クラスSqlDb)を記述し、フォームを開いて後で実行、ここまではうまくいきました。前回の質問では、ここが解決されました。

しかしその後、それらのクラスをクラスライブラリ化し、別にWindowsフォームのプロジェクトを立ち上げ、そこで先ほど作成した『SQLitePackage.dll』を参照に追加し、いざフォームのコード内で使用すると、『SQLite.Interop.dll』がないと例外が出ます。確認すると、確かにプロジェクト内にはそれらのファイルがなく、x86,x64などのフォルダも作成されていません。

その後、クラスライブラリを作成したように、呼び出し側のWindowsフォームアプリケーションでもNuGetで同SQLite.Coreをインストールすると、正しく動きようになりました。

やりたいことは、呼び出し側のWindowsフォームのプロジェクトでは、自作したDLL、『SQLitePackage.dll』のみを参照追加するだけでSQLiteを使用できるようにしたいのです。

どうしてもプロジェクトごとNuGetのインストールが発生してしまうのですが、これを省略することはできないのでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 関連質問へのリンクを含めておくと、読み手に対してより親切になるかと思います。

Comment: SQLite.Interop.dllをSQLitePackage.dllと同じフォルダーに入れてもだめですか？

Comment: 『同じフォルダ』というのは、実行ファイルやSystem.Data.SQLite.dllなどのような『Debug』や『Release』のフォルダの中…ということですか？それだと32ビット版と64ビット版の、同じ名前の二つのファイルを入れることになってしまい、片方が上書きされます。仮にPCのビット数に対応したdllのみを同じフォルダに格納するにしても、その作業は『参照の追加』からではなく、エクスぷローラーからの操作になるため、あまり良い方法ではありません。ただ、『その方法しかないよ』ということならば、当然致し方ないとは思いますが…。

Comment: これらの記事を参考に、自作ライブラリをNuGetパッケージ化し、依存するパッケージの情報を記述しておけば良いのでは？ [自作クラスライブラリで参照設定しているDLLが呼び出せない](https://teratail.com/questions/112531), [【Nuget】C#の自作ライブラリをNugetパッケージ化する方法](https://qiita.com/ronkabu/items/9f957896baa0a5a2d36e), [NuGetパッケージの開発と公開](https://techinfoofmicrosofttech.osscons.jp/index.php?NuGet%E3%83%91%E3%83%83%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%81%AE%E9%96%8B%E7%99%BA%E3%81%A8%E5%85%AC%E9%96%8B#kd3ca09a) 最低限自作ライブラリのNuGetパッケージ1つをインストール指定する必要がありますが、他の依存するパッケージは自動的にインストール対象にリストアップされると思うのですが。

Comment: 事象はまさに紹介してくださっている一つ目の記事です。記事の内容ではオラクルでしたが、私はSQLiteというだけです。確かに、NuGetにしてしまうという方法が最良なのかもしれません。ただ、あるものは『参照の追加』で事足りるのに、ものによってはNuGet化しないといけないというのも、少し違和感を感じます。ありがとうございました。

Comment: DLLの参照パスにSQLite.Interop.dllがあれば問題ないと思いますが、入っていますか？http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/96A79A8774085653862575BC00267966

Answer (score 2):

[System.Data.SQLite.Core](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki#nativeLibraryPreLoading)では

> - \App.exe (optional, managed-only application executable assembly)
> - \App.dll (optional, managed-only application library assembly)
> - \System.Data.SQLite.dll (required, managed-only core assembly)
> - \System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll (optional, managed-only LINQ assembly)
> - \System.Data.SQLite.EF6.dll (optional, managed-only EF6 assembly)
> - \x86\SQLite.Interop.dll (required, x86 native interop assembly)
> - \x64\SQLite.Interop.dll (required, x64 native interop assembly)

というディレクトリ構成を想定しているので、これが実現できるようにSQLite.Interop.dllをコピーしましょう。

Comment: 具体的には、`x86\SQLite.Interop.dll` `x64\SQLite.Interop.dll` をプロジェクトに追加して、それぞれのプロパティの「出力ディレクトリにコピー」を「新しい場合はコピーする」に設定することで出力されます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。多分、的を得ている回答だと思うのですが、その操作方法はどうすればよいですか？『プロジェクトに追加』というのは、『参照の追加』から行うのでしょうか？それとも、やはりエクスぷローラーから手動で行うということですか？また、『「出力ディレクトリにコピー」を「新しい場合はコピーする」に設定』というのはどこから行うものですか？

Comment: エクスプローラーからVisualStudioのソリューションエクスクローラーの追加したいプロジェクトにドラッグ＆ドロップしてください。プロパティは追加されたdllを選択するとVisualStudioのプロパティウィンドウに表示されます。

Comment: ↑参照の追加は不要です。やってることは、プロジェクトに追加されているファイルをそのまま出力フォルダーにコピーする設定、になります。

Answer (score 0):

自己レスです。

どうやら現在の環境での解決策は、NuGetを自作するのが最も良いようです。回答していただいた皆様、ありがとうございました。